# I want to have pbox have line breaks where the margin falls

Tags: tables, line-breaking

I am using `\pbox` to have line breaks in a table, but cannot seem to figure out how to have it break at the "natural" location where the margin begins.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pbox}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{tabular}{ll}
First cell & \pbox[t]{\columnwidth}{This is a long block of text that is not breaking where I would like it to break and as you can see it does not break eventually, but not until it hits the edge of the page.}
\end{tabular}
And this is another long block of text outside the tabular environment which has a line break where I would like it to be, that is, where the margin begins.
%
\end{document}
```

Does anyone know a command I can use to fix this? I have tried `\columnwidth` and `\paperwidth` as the length parameters of the `\pbox` command, but they both result in the same problem.

Also please note that I would like some sort of macro, rather than manually setting the length to `5in` or whatever it is to the margin.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx, note you can use the `{}` button (or simply indent by 4 spaces to format code sections (see my edit)

Comment: Unrelated note: As option to `geometry` you can use `margin=1in` instead of defining the margins for all four sides of the page (since they are all the same).

Comment: Figured out how to format code, is there an easy way to show what the code outputs, so people don't need to copy-paste and compile to see what the MWE is doing?

Answer (score 4):

There is no no need to use `\pbox` to have multi-cell entries. (It is just a nested `tabular` anyway. Simply use `p` columns instead of `l`. To have the width of the column determined automatically, use `X` from `tabularx`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}

First cell & This is a long block of text that is not breaking where I would like it to break and as you can see it does break eventually, but not until it hits the edge of the page.

\end{tabularx}

And this is another long block of text outside the tabular environment which has a line break where I would like it to be, that is, where the margin begins.
\end{document}
```